# Python: Listen to Process Started

Tags: python

While copying large data files over network drives:

```
cmd=None
if sys.platform.startswith("darwin"): cmd=['cp', source, dest]
elif sys.platform.startswith("win"): cmd=['xcopy', source, dest, '/K/O/X']
if cmd: proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I wonder if there's a way to hook to started process to get feedback: such as a network transfer data rate... any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want it to :)

```
if cmd:
  proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
  result = proc.communicate()[0]
  print result
```

this should do what you want.

Comment: I need to clarify: a solution needs to be applicable to operation system's "copy" command... not just generic. On Mac a variable 'result' results to zero length string when file copied from/to same local disk. I am not sure it is different when data sent to network drive.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the "feedback" means but you can get the current status of copy by using multithreading.

You can have one thread who keeps doing

```
du -h file_name
```

This link has more info - 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66795/how-to-check-progress-of-running-cp

Comment: That could be it since I do use multiprocessing's Pool... Thanks!